# How to increase streets name size/readability?

Tags: android, osmdroid

I'm currently rendering my map on osmdroid using the following code:

The problem is that I'm running the app on a GS6 Edge, and it's completely impossible to read the street names: http://img.ctrlv.in/img/15/10/03/560f4427e54c9.png

Is it possible to increase the street name size or even increase the zoom? (It's currently set to 100)

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getActivity().setTitle(FRAGMENT_NAME);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_view, container, false);


    mMapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mMapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.DEFAULT_TILE_SOURCE);
    mMapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);

    mMapController = (MapController) mMapView.getController();
    mMapController.setZoom(100);

    GeoPoint gPt = new GeoPoint(-23.5784,-46.4078);
    mMapController.setCenter(gPt);

    return view;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using Mapnik (aka OSM) map tiles, which are rastered graphics. The only way to make it bigger (that I know of) is to either a) use a different tile source (try bing), or b) try using osmbonuspack + mapsforge (which can render OSM tiles on the fly and thus can control the font size).